# SQL SELECT data from table group by different data

Tags: sql, oracle

Display pymtmode, and total number of payments for those payments which were paid before the year 2015 and total number of payments should be more than 1 from the data given:

```
ORDERID QUOTATIONID QTYORDERED  ORDERDATE   STATUS  PYMTDATE    DELIVEREDDATE   AMOUNTPAID  PYMTMODE
O1001   Q1002   100 30-OCT-14   Delivered   05-NOV-14   05-NOV-14   140000  Cash
O1003   Q1003   50  15-DEC-14   Delivered   18-DEC-14   20-DEC-14   310000  Cash
O1004   Q1006   100 15-DEC-14   Delivered   25-DEC-14   30-DEC-14   80000   Cheque
O1005   Q1002   50  30-JAN-15   Delivered   01-FEB-15   03-FEB-15   70000   Cheque
O1006   Q1008   75  20-FEB-15   Delivered   22-FEB-15   23-FEB-15   161250  Cash
```

I've tried the below code for fetching Year and select only values before the year 2015 and grouping by year.

```
SELECT pymtmode, COUNT(*) as pymtcount 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY to_char(pymtdate, 'Year') 
HAVING to_char(pymtdate,'Year')<2015 AND count(*)>1
```

I've learnt that group by columns/functions should be mentioned in SELECT statement as well. But this question and it's expected result doesn't relate with it. Clarity with basic explanations would help

> Expected Result

```
PYMTMODE    PYMTCOUNT
  Cash         2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result needs `pymtmode` to be selected, so you must `GROUP BY pymtmode` and not `GROUP BY to_char(pymtdate, 'Year')`, because you don't need to get results for each year, right?.
Also the condition `to_char(pymtdate,'Year')<2015` might as well be put in a `WHERE` clause, so to restrict the rows before aggregation:

```
SELECT pymtmode, COUNT(*) as pymtcount 
FROM orders 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pymtmode) < 2015
GROUP BY pymtmode 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get you! But "ORA-01722: invalid number" error is thrown when your code is tried. Any help?

Comment: I found the error. It was actually `to_char(pymtdate,'YYYY')` with your previous answer.

Comment: Yes, I copied it from your question. Change to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using direct date comparisons for this purpose:

```
SELECT o.pymtmode, COUNT(*) as pymtcount 
FROM orders o
WHERE o.pymtdate < DATE '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY o.pymtmode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Notes:

- You want to do the filtering *before* the aggregation, not afterwards.  I think that is the source of your confusion.
- A direct comparison to dates makes it easier for the optimizer to generate the best execution plan.
- Learning how to use table aliases (the `o`) is a good habit.

Comment: I've been using table aliases with JOIN statements, using it in normal queries also is a new learning for me. Thanks @Gordon!
P.S. Someone Downvoted this question, don't even know why! Reputation lowered :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select pymtmode, count(pymtmode) pymtcount from orders where extract(year from to_date(pymtdate))<2015 group by pymtmode having count(pymtmode)>1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, pls do consider of explaining it and how it would help for the long-term value - so that others can learn from this. This keeps the value of SO high, and increases your chances of getting upvotes.